# Model values saved as object ( <Model_Name object>) in DB rather than simple values

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I have a model called `Love` as

```
class Love(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ans = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
```

and a `ModelForm`

```
class LoveForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Love
        fields = ('ans',)
```

and my views to display this form and save data in DB is

```
def love_form(request):
#user can input as my answers he wants to thats wht multiple times rendering the same template

    form = LoveForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoveForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            answer = form.save(commit=False)
            answer.user = request.user
            answer.save()
            return render(request, 'purpose_using_DB/love_form.html', {'form': form, 'message': 'Successfully Saved'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'purpose_using_DB/love_form.html', {'form': form, 'message': 'Error Occured'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'purpose_using_DB/love_form.html', {'form': form})
```

but the problem is that the **Data saved in DB after `admin.site.register(Love)` is shown as an object rather than the `ans` values**

Is this normal? Why it isn't showing the values like `ans=something` in the admin ?

Comment: how did you check that?

Comment: registering the model in Admin and then checking it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django admin doesn't know how to represent an object as an string so you should handle it yourself (current behavior is correct)

start with customizing [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

```
class LoveAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["user", "ans"] 
    # other stuff
```

as the result it will show a nice table in admin page with two columns (user and answer)